# How to make a dictionary data from Firestore conform to sequence? I want use one of the fields and add the Integers together

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have a compactmap of the the data from the cloud Firestore, however I need access to just one of the variables and iterate over it to add up the Integers stored there.
My data contains Dates and does not conform to Sequence and I am struggling to find a solution

My data:

```
struct Travel: Identifiable, Equatable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    var reason: String
    var date: Date
    var numDays: Int
```

Firestore fetch:

```
func fetchData() async throws -> [Travel] {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return [] }
        let snapshot = try await reference1.document(uid).collection("dates")
            .order(by: "date", descending: true)
            .getDocuments()
        return snapshot.documents.compactMap { document in
            try! document.data(as: Travel.self)
        }
    }
```

I need a way to access the numDays data and add together all the values for all the data saved.

I have tried for loops but as Travel doesn't conform to Sequence I cannot do that.

I then have the viewModel:

```
    @Published var travel: Loadable<[Travel]> = .loading
    
    
        func fetchPosts() {
                Task {
                    do {
                        travel = .loaded(try await datesRepository.fetchData())
                    } catch {
                        print("[ViewModel] Cannot fetch posts: \(error)")
                        travel = .error(error)
                    }
                }
            }
```

Any attempts to do a for loop on this data hasn't worked.
Please help

Comment: But you don’t have a Travel object, you have an array of Travel objects and Array conforms to Sequence.

Comment: Added more information to main thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you want to take an array of `Travel` objects, pull out the value of `numDays` and add all of them together? If so, you can use `.reduce`.

```
let travelArray: [Travel] = ...
let totalDays = travelArray.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.numDays }
```

This translates to "take your array and perform a reduce starting at 0, adding each `Travel` object's `numDays` value to the running total in reduce and return the total."

Comment: Thanks for your help! I ended up using this for strings too

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that you pass in an array of your Travel objects and use the .reduce method to sum up the days and return it if you want. Something like this:

```
func calculateTotalNumDays(travels: [Travel]) -> Int {
    let totalNumDays = travels.reduce(0) { (result, travel) in
        return result + travel.numDays
    }
    return totalNumDays
}

//Example
do {
    let fetchedTravels = try await datesRepository.fetchData()
    let totalNumDays = calculateTotalNumDays(travels: fetchedTravels)
    print("Total numDays: \(totalNumDays)")
} catch {
    print("Error fetching data: \(error)")
}
```